# Should yarn.lock be treated as a binary file in git?

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

Is there a reason for not doing so?

My idea is that the potential git diff will happen in package.json. I would like to treat the yarn.lock as a binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this question in Yarn's issue tracker on GitHub. I got the following answer:

> No it shouldn't. The file is plain text and there can be merge
>   conflicts in the file that you may need to resolve.

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1776#issuecomment-260022242

Comment: There have been updates in the issue. For anyone reading this, it's worth to check the issue to see the recommended method of resolving the merge conflicts.

Comment: Staring down the barrel of 97 merge conflicts.  This file!

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any reason to not treat it as so, as it is a file which is not meant to be read by humans.

I have been using it as a binary in a large team for more than one year and we didn't have any problems. And nobody who I talked to run into problems too - please comment if you have, as I am trying to implement it again in another company.

Merge conflicts can be resolved [installing the packages again](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/3544). Talk with your team about this topic and give it a go.